# Is there a way to set specific compression scheme when saving tiff file in opencv?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, compression, tiff

I'm using opencv to crop tif files, everthing is fine, except for saving image to a file - opencv always uses LZW compression, but i don't need compression on resulting files, i do appreciate opencv's help in saving my disk drive space, but now is not the right time to do it. 
So is there a way to save tif files with specific compression scheme (including no compression) or no? 
Original images have no compression scheme applied and i'm using ROI to select area and SaveImage to save it to the target file. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TIFF compression level is hard coded and cant be changed at run time. If you are compiling OpenCV on your machine, then you can edit the compression level in this file

```
3rdparty/libtiff/tiff.h
```

you will find this line:

```
#define     COMPRESSION_LZW     5       /* Lempel-Ziv  & Welch */
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: see this line in the opencv code:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b46719b0931b256ab68d5f833b8fadd83737ddd1/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp#L564
you should be able to pass the desired value for TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, including COMPRESSION_NONE.

Comment: Meh, this isn't good, I will check it out in day or two, i don't have a opportunity to download sources right now, so it will take some time. Thanks!

Comment: @fireant, Do you know where in the OpenCV sources should the hard coded compression method be changed? The `3rdparty/libtiff/tiff.h` you mentioned is the part of libtiff itself and contains definitions for various compression methods including `#define COMPRESSION_CCITT_T6 4 /* CCITT T.6 (TIFF 6 name) */`. So actually we need to find where in OpenCV usages of these definitions are hard coded.

Comment: @alexander-abakumov I updated the answer, see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @fireant, Thank you! This is exactly the same line that I changed a few hours ago :)

Answer (score 5):

In OpenCV 3 you can supply a vector of parameters to change things like compression or lines per strip, as in:

```
vector<int> params = { 
    259, 1,     // No compression, turn off default LZW
    279, 64     // Rows per strip 
};
imwrite("image.tiff", myImage, params);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work to save CCITTG4 tiff image. Probably because the Mat is at least a 8 bits matrix.