# OpenCV java implementaiton of Mat.dump() returns inaccurate data

Tags: java, opencv

I'm looking for extracting image pixel data into a list of integers (or any number representation). E.g., having a 2 x 2 white image, the result will be [255,255,255,255]. The Mat.dump() method prints the image pixel values accurately if the image was code generated and not read form the disk:

```
    Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
    Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
    mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
    Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
    mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data, "+m.total()+" elements:\n" + 
    m.dump());
```

prints accurately=>

```
    OpenCV Mat: Mat [ 5*10*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, 
    nativeObj=0x1415d50, dataAddr=0x13a6880 ]
    OpenCV Mat data, 50 elements:
    [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0;
       1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   5,   1,   1,   1,   1;
       0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0;
       0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0;
       0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

but if I write the Mat "m" contents on the disk and afterwards I read it again, the dump() method spits out strange output:

```
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.jpg",m);

    m = null;
    m = Imgcodecs.imread(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.jpg");
    System.out.println("Fresly read m, "+m.total()+" elements:\n"+m.dump());
```

prints

```
Fresly read m, 50 elements:
[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   
5,   5,   5,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   
5,   5,   5,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1;
0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   5,   
5,   5,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   4,   
4,   4,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   
5,   5,   5,   1,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

Due to the fact i need to extract the int values from read images, and relying on dump() for the string representation, this causes me trouble.

**EDIT:**

I have managed to extract the data simply using

```
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols(); j++) {
            values.add((int)m.get(i,j)[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, the dump() method distorts any disk-read image data, not only code-written images through Imgcodecs.imwrite()

Comment: JPEG is a lossy file format. You won't necessarily get back the same data you write.

Comment: @AndyTurner that may be, but then why does the .total() return just 50 elems? Also, the byte size of the image was the same before and after the re-reading

Answer (score 1):

Mat.dump() is our friend as is printing the mat name to reveal its properties.  (The question title should be changed not to disparage dump().)  imread automatically assumes conversion to BGR thus the 3 channels of data instead of the expected 1 channel.  imwrite JPEG automatically compresses somewhat.  You can control the imread conversion and lessen the compression but it's still a little lossy.

```java
MatOfInt imwrite_flags = new MatOfInt();
imwrite_flags.fromArray(Imgcodecs.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY , 100);
Imgcodecs.imwrite(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.jpg",m, imwrite_flags);

m = Imgcodecs.imread(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.jpg", Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

What you need is no or lossless compression so use TIFF format - example of both below with TIFF.  (See [Is there a way to set specific compression scheme when saving tiff file in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205417/is-there-a-way-to-set-specific-compression-scheme-when-saving-tiff-file-in-openc))

```java
String TRAIN_PATH_PROC = "";

Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data, "+m.total()+" elements:\n" + 
m.dump());

MatOfInt imwrite_flags = new MatOfInt();
imwrite_flags.fromArray(Imgcodecs.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION , 1); // no compression
Imgcodecs.imwrite(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m2.tif",m, imwrite_flags);// note name change so both examples can run
// OR
Imgcodecs.imwrite(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.tif",m); // default compression LZW grayscale but lossless, I think

m = null;
m = Imgcodecs.imread(TRAIN_PATH_PROC+"m.tif", Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
System.out.println("Fresly read m, "+m.total()+" elements:\n"+m.dump());
```